# Why does WCF deserialize empty strings as valid enumerations

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, enums, enumeration

Let's say for example I have a C# data contract written like this

```
[DataContract]
public class GiftCard
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public PaymentMethod MethodOfPayment;
}

[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum PaymentMethod
{
    [EnumMember]
    Mastercard = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Visa = 1
}
```

Then test it using SOAPUI, deliberately not specifying a value.

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <GiftCardTest>
     <GiftCard>
        <MethodOfPayment></MethodOfPayment>
     </GiftCard>
  </GiftCardTest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

It arrives in my service method as valid  [image: Visual Studio Watch]

What attributes am I missing?  How do I validate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the Flags attribute did the trick.

```
[DataContract]
public enum PaymentMethod
{
    [EnumMember]
    Mastercard = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Visa = 1
}
```

It now throws an exception:

> Invalid enum value '' cannot be deserialized into type 'PaymentMethod'...

Comment: When you have `Flags` set, a value of `String.Empty` will be interpreted as  "no flags set" which is 0. If you are using flags your first flag needs to start at 1. However just removing `Flags` makes the most sense in this case because it does not make sense to have a `MethodOfPayment` that is both a Visa and Mastercard at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Flags was a relic from another enum with non-sequential indexes.

Answer (score 0):

When it desearalizes the value it must set a default value if it could not find a valid value to use during deserialization. So it uses `default(PaymentMethod)` which is the same as doing `(PaymentMethod)default(int)`.

The value of `default(int)` is 0, you must either make 0 a non valid enum value or make `MethodOfPayment` nullable so the default value will  be `null` instead of 0.

Comment: I would have assumed that if it had `EmitDefaultValue = false`, then it would not interpret empty strings as default values.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd it still needs to assign a value to the property or throw a exception. Because the OP used the flags attribute not passing a value is the same as saying "Don't set any flags" and will set the enum to 0. Because the 0 value was a valid value it used MasterCard.